# Why does the POSIX for-loop allow a `for name in ; do` (no words in list) syntax?

Tags: bash, posix

I'm trying to understand the for-loop syntax in the [POSIX shell grammar rules](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02):

```
for_clause       : For name                                      do_group
                 | For name                       sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in          sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group
```

The last (pretty much the default) and the two first makes sense, quoting from posix:

> Omitting:
> `in word...`
> shall be equivalent to:
> `in "$@"`

so the first two are just looping over the arguments to the shell script.

I just don't understand how a for-loop consisting of `for name in; do echo $name; done` makes sense. I thought it was still just looping over the arguments to the shell script, but creating a small script it doesn't seem to be the case. The for loop just kinda seems to get ignore.
So what is the purpose of that third variation?

Comment: "The for loop just kinda seems to get ignore[d]." Nope, it's there. The syntax is correct, but there's nothing to do. And if you don't do anything, how do you know when you're done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just that `wordlist` is defined as:

```
wordlist         : wordlist WORD
                 |          WORD
```

So *one or more* words, but the `for var in ...; do ...; done` loop can loop over *zero or more* words, so it needs `For name linebreak in sequential_sep do_group` to cover the case of *zero words*.

Having `wordlist` defined as *zero or more words*:

```
wordlist         : wordlist WORD
                 | /* empty */
```

Would probably have been less confusing.

If you look at [SUSv2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_010), there was:

```
 for_clause       : For name linebreak                            do_group
                  | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group
```

```
 wordlist         : wordlist WORD
                  |          WORD
```

Meaning that an empty list was not allowed. So it looks like what happened is that in SUSv3, they fixed that omission by adding the:

```
For name linebreak in sequential_sep do_group
```

Rather than changing the definition of `wordlist`.

---

Note that we're talking of the shell language grammar here, so it's not about `for i in $var; do ...; done` or `for i in $(some cmd); do ...; done` where `$var`/`$(some cmd)` expansions could result in an empty list. Those `$var`, `$(some cmd)` are each one WORD token in POSIX formalisation of the shell language.

We *are* talking of `for i in; do ...; done`, where there is literally no *WORD* in between the `in` and the `do`.

I agree that code is not particularly useful. There is little reason for one to write a loop that explicitly loops over nothing. Some reasons that one could think of:

Generated code:

```
if ...; then
  list=' "foo" "bar baz" "$var" '
else
  list=
fi

eval '
  for i in '"$list"'; do
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
  done
'
```

Or anything that generates `sh` scripts and constructs a `for` loop over explicit arguments.

Or to comment out some code:

```
for commented_out in; do
  this code is commented out
done
```

Though something like:

```
:||:<<'EOF'
  this code is commented out and (harmless) even
  if it contains invalid syntax
EOF
```

Would be more idiomatic.

I did not find the change request that led to the modification of the standard, but I suppose they changed it mainly because all existing shell implementations allowed `for i in; do ...; done`, so there was no point forbidding it in the standard.

You'll find that it doesn't allow `if then ...; else ...; fi` nor `if; then ...; else ...; fi` nor `if ...; then;else ...; fi`¹ (but allows `if $empty; then $empty; else $empty; fi` obviously) even if there's no real good reason to forbid it, because most implementations (`zsh` being a notable exception), starting with the Bourne shell which introduced it and the Korn shell on which the POSIX `sh` specification is based in practice choke on it.

---

<sup>¹ Actually, in the Bourne shell that did not have the `!` keyword to negate the exit status of a pipeline, you had to write `if cmd; then :; else command if cmd fails; fi` in place of `if ! cmd; then command if cmd fails; fi`, that is use an explicit `:` null-command in the the `then` part as the Bourne shell did not allow an empty `then` part.</sup>

Comment: Though, as far as that's "words" before expansions, so that e.g. `"$@"` or `$a` count as such regardless of how many fields eventually appear, disallowing the empty list would really only come up in generated code. But perhaps that's enough to warrant the change, and it does make the result more orthogonal in any case.

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes, though most likely the main reason POSIX fixed it was that all existing implementations allowed `for i in; do ...; done`, so there was no reason to forbid it even if that's not particularly useful (except as you say that it could come from generated code as in `eval 'for i in '"$quoted_words"'; do ...; done`, or could be used to comment out some code).

Comment: While this is a good point worth making, I don't think this should be the accepted answer, because it isn't the answer. The grammar is not the reason the language is what it is. We don't write grammars first and then make our language fit the grammar, it's the other way round.

Comment: @renierpost, I agree the working of my answer is not ideal. But.  In the first part, I explain why the grammar rules are worded like that, in the second part why `for i in; do...` is allowed by the grammar (mostly because the implementations the POSIX specification tries to describe (POSIX, at least initially was more descriptive than prescriptive) allowed it).

Comment: @reinierpost, well, the author of the question knows best what they mean with the question, and they have the unbounded authority to set the "accepted" mark, so...

Comment: @ilkkachu yes of course; it is just a comment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I would reverse the order for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

The reasoning for this behavior is best illustrated with an example. Assume you have a variable named `${items}` and you need to call a function on each word in that variable, but it might evaluate to an empty string in some cases.

With POSIX compliant behavior, you can just use:

```bash
for x in ${items} ; do
   do_something(x)
done
```

Here, it doesn’t matter if `${items}` evaluates to an empty string or not, because if it does, the loop will have nothing to loop over and will just be skipped.

But if the shell handled the case of an empty word list differently (either not at all, or equivalent to one of the forms without the `in`), then you would instead need (at minimum):

```bash
if [ -n "${items}" ]; then
    for x in ${items} ; do
        do_something(x)
    done
fi
```

So this behavior saves you (at minimum) a level of indentation and an extra conditional check in the relatively common case of having to iterate over a potentially empty list of items of unknown length. Many other languages that have for loops which iterate over a collection of items (such as Python or JavaScript) also behave in exactly the same manner, they just explicitly require a variable (or literal) to be provided to the loop, while shell script does not appear to because of how a literal list of items to loop over is defined (namely, an empty one is just an unquoted empty string).

Comment: No. What the OP is quoting is the language grammar. In `for x in ${items}`, `${items}` is a WORD in the grammar regardless of how the `${items}` would expand. In any case, with `${items}` unquoted, it's subject to split+glob so could expand to an empty list if if the `$items` variable was not empty (like when it contains only space, tab and newline characters with the default value of `$IFS`).

Comment: Especially from the last paragraph of the question, it seems OP is actually asking "how does this make sense" or "why would you need that", not "which part of the grammar allows that" or "why is the grammar defined the way it is". And that question is answered nicely by this answer.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, except that as commented above, this answer doesn't consider the case of `for x in; do` with an empty list. In the shell grammar section linked in the Q, there's a link to [Token recognition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03), which explains how tokens with expansions are recognized, and goes on to say that "The characters found from the beginning of the substitution to its end ... shall be included unmodified in the result token, including any embedded or enclosing substitution operators or quotes.".

Comment: note also how in the description of the [for loop](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03), it's mentioned that "the list of words following 'in' shall be expanded to generate a list of items.". The "items" that appear from expansions are distinct from the "words" that contain the raw expansion syntax.

Comment: If the various expansions were done before the shell code is actually parsed, you could do things like `for x $empty in a b c; do` (where `$empty` expands to nothing), or `for $name in a b c; do` (where the variable `name` contains the name of the variable to use in the loop), or even `$op [ something... ]; do ...` (where `op` could be either `while` or `until`), and worse. It'd also make handling arbitrary data impossible, as something like `somecmd "$foo" "$bar" "$doo"` would run the command named by `doo`, if `bar` happened to contain `;`.